# C# WPF Menu Item Background color

Tags: c#, wpf, background, menuitem

I have a program in C# WPF (.NET 4.0 Framework)

Since i am fairly new with WPF (came from Windows Forms) i wonder how i can fix this issue.
I have a Menu Control at top with all my needed Items and i have set the Background color of the Menu Control to ControlLightLight (System Color, similar to white) however when i click on a Menu Item to see my Sub Items the Background color is not the same. So what i did is change the Background color for the sub items, but it gets messed up: [Screen-Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOtCa.png)

Good screenshot showing the problem:

All i wanted is the grey color to be like the white one (ControlLightLight): [Screen-Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6NF8.png)

**EDIT:**

Heres the code with the background i used:

```
                <MenuItem x:Name="mnuHelp" Header="Help">
                <MenuItem Header="Check for Updates" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightLightBrushKey}}"/>
                <MenuItem Header="About"/>
            </MenuItem>
```

Comment: Are you running into this problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515210/wpf-menuitem-border